# How to handle a persistent http connection using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating service A that communicates with service B over http requests. Since my system needs to support high load of usage, I wanted to create a persistent connection.

I am working with python `requests` library. I thought of creating a `requests.Session` object and just keep using the same object for all http requests.

What happens if for some reason the underlying tcp connection was lost? How can I check the session object is still alive and healthy? I tried googling but haven't found anything...

Thank you :)

Comment: Sessions are kept alive by default due to urllib3 handling the connection pool for the session. I'm not sure there is a method to check it's status other than attempting to use it occasionally. In general I think using sessions is fine and assuming it will reuse for you appropriately is also fine. I don't know if there is a big benefit to explicitly knowing the status of the session rather than just attempting to use it and reestablishing it on error? This isn't my top area so I'll leave this as a comment and maybe someone else will have a better opinion.